# mongoose.connect giving error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using node to connect to mongoose database, but when i run the code, it gives error as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
  (anonymous function)  server.js:13
```

Below is the code which i am running in server.js

```
var express= require(['express']);
var bodyParser = require(['body-parser']);
var cookieParser = require(['cookie-parser']);
var expressSession = require(['express-session']);
var mongoose = require(['mongoose']);

var mongoStore = require(['connect-mongo'])({session: expressSession});
require(['./models/users.js']);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userregistration');
var app = express();
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine','html');

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'SECRET',
    cookie: {maxAge:60*60*1000 },
    store: new mongoStore({
        db: mongoose.connection.db,
        collection: 'sessions'
    })

}));

require('./routes')(app);
app.listen(80);
```

looking at the logs, the code is giving the error at:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userregistration');
```

Comment: Have you tried to establish a db connection with port no ?

Comment: @WaqasAhmed: Its not about port number...Its mongoose.connect is giving error saying, its undefined.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to require express-session.

Here is the example

[ExpressSession](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-sessions)

```
app.use(express.session({
  secret: 'SECRET',
  cookie: {maxAge:60*60*1000 },
  store: new mongoStore({
    db: mongoose.connection.db,
    collection: 'sessions'
  })
}));
```

Comment: I have installed express-session using npm install -g express-session --save, but still the issue exists...

Comment: Hi, looking at the error trace, the error is coming at "mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userregistration');".

Answer (score 0):

`connect-mongo` has a special option for using Mongoose connections, try using that:

```
store: new mongoStore({
    mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection,
    collection: 'sessions'
})
```

If that doesn't fix it, please post more information (like a full stack trace and the *actual* code you're running, since those `require`'s don't look right).

Comment: Hi, looking at the error trace, the error is coming at "mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userregistration');"

Answer (score 0):

```
// Replace 'db' by  'mongooseConnection '

app.use(expressSession({
secret: 'SECRET',
cookie: {maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000},
store: new mongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    collection: 'sessions'
  })
}));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, don't post only code, so the OP can learn from it